# Генерация pdf при помощи PHP

Tags: pdf, php

Доброго времени суток!
В целом задача такова: Существует база данных MySQL с набором таблиц данных. Необходимо с помощью PHP вытягивать данные, и генерировать PDF документы (Отчеты, Ведомости, Формы и тд).

Хотелось бы узнать о существующих средствах с помощью которых , требуемая задача решалась наиболее корректно.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

[Mpdf](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php)

Comment: А как с форматированием, изображениями и диаграммами?)

Comment: Я где-то видел класс для генерации PDF из HTML, только в упор не помню, как называется. Попробуй поискать

Comment: Вот интересно , что с диаграммами придумывать...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tcpdf.org/

Comment: А как с форматированием, изображениями и диаграммами?)

Comment: Сам не пользовался, но народ здесь его рекомендует. Попробуйте по поиску найти похожие вопросы. Кто-то когда-то предлагал этот класс.

Comment: Ну я сам о нем наслышан, просто думал есть уже более продвинутые решения.